# How can I generate a form with CRUD operations from a class using c#?

Tags: c#

I have a configuration class with 100 fields. I wish to create a GUI for it.
It is a lot of work mapping each text box to the public methods of the class.
Is there a way to generate the form automatically from a class in c#?

```
class Configuration
{
   public string ServiceBusNamespace {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

Comment: Like a [PropertyGrid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid)? I'm assuming this is WinForms.

Comment: I tried it, it works for simple items, i have nested classes, is it possible to display classes as a tree in propertygrid?

Comment: Yes, you can do nested classes with a PropertyGrid.